# Бинарное дерево префиксной формулы

Tags: c++, дерево

Решаю задачки, наткнулся на следующую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно решал-решал, вроде как всё простроил, но тестирующая система указывает на то, что 2 ответа из 11 -  неверные. Попросил один из двух тестов, которые дают неверный ответ у меня, вот такой тест у меня не проходит: `-+/*+36+--+*2--+/+8*9*+*+3*/6519-**+**4-+/-/3+1*-*287-97+*+*++*22**3+*33451778921491874825497385431`
Вот такой ответ должен быть:**307151970**, мой ответ **-1840331677**
Но дело обстоит интереснее, я собственными руками построил это дерево и мой ответ сошёлся с моим кодом и соответственно не сошёлся с ответом тестирующей системы, вот моё дерево по этому тесту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри вершин - соответствующие знаки и цифры из теста, снаружи чёрным цветом их номер во входной строке из теста(начиная с нуля), зелёным цветом у некоторых подписано соответствующее им значение. Не понимаю что может быть не так. Прикрепляю также свой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
string prov;
bool IsCifra(char a)
{
    if (a != '*' && a != '+' && a != '-' && a != '/')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
long long calculator(long long f, char a, long long s)
{
    if (a == '*')
    {
        return f * s;
    }
    if (a == '+')
    {
        return f + s;
    }
    if (a == '-')
    {
        return f - s;
    }
    if (s == 0)
    {
        prov = "NO";
        return 0;
    }
    return f / s;
}
class Tree
{
public:
    struct TreeElement
    {
        int child1_pos, child2_pos;
        char val;
    };
private:
    size_t tree_size_;
    TreeElement* tree_ptr_;
    long long deep_calculate(const int& pos);
    int deep_add(const int& pos, const string& s);
public:
    Tree(const size_t& element_count, const string& s);
    ~Tree()
    {
        delete[] tree_ptr_;
    }
    long long calculate();
};
Tree::Tree(const size_t& element_count, const string& s)
{
    this->tree_ptr_ = new TreeElement[element_count];
    this->tree_size_ = element_count;
    tree_ptr_[0].val = s[0];
    tree_ptr_[s.size() - 1].child1_pos = -1;
    tree_ptr_[s.size() - 1].child2_pos = -1;
    deep_add(0, s);
}
long long Tree::calculate()
{
    return deep_calculate(0);
}
long long Tree::deep_calculate(const int& pos)
{
    if (prov == "NO")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (IsCifra(tree_ptr_[pos].val))
    {
        return tree_ptr_[pos].val - '0';
    }
    long long first = deep_calculate(tree_ptr_[pos].child1_pos), second = deep_calculate(tree_ptr_[pos].child2_pos);
    long long zn = calculator(first, tree_ptr_[pos].val, second);
    return zn;
}
int Tree::deep_add(const int& pos, const string& s)
{
    TreeElement* arr = tree_ptr_;
    // считаем, что первый ребёнок всегда на +1 ячейку от родителя
    arr[pos].child1_pos = pos + 1;
    arr[pos + 1].val = s[pos + 1];
    if (IsCifra(arr[arr[pos].child1_pos].val))
    {
        //первый ребёнок - цифра, тогда второй ребёнок идёт сразу после первого в строке
        arr[pos + 1].child1_pos = -1;
        arr[pos + 1].child2_pos = -1;

        arr[pos].child2_pos = pos + 2;
        arr[pos + 2].val = s[pos + 2];
        //закинули данные
    }
    else
    {
        //первый ребёнок не цифра и надо понять, где лежит второй ребёнок
        //запускаем для первого ребёнка 
        int child2pos;
        child2pos = deep_add(pos + 1, s);
        //заполняем
        arr[pos].child2_pos = child2pos + 1;
        arr[child2pos + 1].val = s[child2pos + 1];
        //готово
    }
    if (IsCifra(arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].val))
    {
        //если вторая - цифра
        arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].child1_pos = -1;
        arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].child2_pos = -1;
        return arr[pos].child2_pos;
    }
    else
    {
        return deep_add(arr[pos].child2_pos, s);
    }
}


int main()
{
    ifstream datain;
    datain.open("input.txt");
    string s;
    datain >> s;
    ofstream dataout;
    dataout.open("output.txt");
    if (s.size() == 1)
    {
        dataout << s[0] - '0';
        return 0;
    }
    Tree tree(s.size(), s);
    long long ans = tree.calculate();
    if (prov == "NO")
    {
        dataout << prov;
    }
    else
    {
        dataout << ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: я написал простенький код, который считает это выражение и мой ответ совпал с требуемым.

Comment: Понимаете, по большому счёту код, который я написал, делает то, что мне требуется. И я вот хочу именно понять, что я делаю не так, считая это выражение ручками.

Comment: Я прошу указать на то, что я делаю не так в своих рассуждениях, рисуя дерево. Для этого и прикрепил его набросок:)

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы понимаете, что дерево не просто большое, а достаточно большое и искать в нем ошибки немного накладно. Я посмотрел код и он мне кажется немного "переусложненным". Особенно  это "первый ребёнок не цифра и надо понять, где лежит второй ребёнок". Сейчас привиду код.

Comment: А есть общая формула для определения позиции "второго ребёнка"?

Comment: Не нужно так делать. Нужно просто делать правильный парсер.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Извините, если простых вещей не понимаю:(

Comment: Вы заметили что `307151970 + 1840331677 = 2^31 - 1`? У вас где-то переполнение.

Comment: Хех и на листочке тоже?)

Comment: Как вы уможали многозначные числа?

Comment: На калькуляторе

Comment: Там к этому ответу делением приходишь, а не умножением, поэтому я переполнение откинул

Comment: Кст написал парсер щас на python и ответ выдал такой же как и у автора вопроса, а после переписал его на c++ и стало выдавать как и требуется по заданию. Скорее всего ошибка возникала при делении целых чисел.

Comment: А в чём она проявляется? Просто не понимаю - какая может быть ошибка при делении целых чисел))

Comment: Ответ -1840331677 верный. Я перепроверил на компьютере ваше дерево. Питон с целочисленным делением в стиле C.

Comment: Правда у других получался именно ответ тестирующей системы. Ничего не понимаю...

Comment: Ответ найден! Мой ответ верен, ответ тестирующей системы нет! Действительно, если  использовать в качестве решения тип ```int``` произойдёт переполнение на одном из шагов и ответ будет как у тестирующей системы, я же использовал ```long long``` и поэтому ответ не сошёлся! Залил в тестирующую систему свой код, но изменил везде ```long long``` на ```int``` после чего все тесты прошли верно) В общем ответы тестирующей системы не верны!

Comment: Оформите вашу находку как ответ (с доказательствами). Я с удовольствием заплюсую.

Comment: А вывод из этой истории такой: если писать на C++ и не убеждаться в отсутствии переполнений, получается чепуха даже у важных людей, которые ведут сайты с задачами по олимпиадному программированию.

Comment: Оформил, как вы и сказали!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ найден! Мой ответ верен, ответ тестирующей системы нет! Действительно, если использовать в качестве решения тип `int` произойдёт переполнение на одном из шагов и ответ будет как у тестирующей системы, я же использовал `long long` и поэтому ответ не сошёлся! Залил в тестирующую систему свой код, но изменил везде `long long` на `int` после чего все тесты прошли верно)
Кидаю скрин с `long long` и с `int`.
Там видно только часть кода, но в силу его размера весь заскринить не получится, там везде `long long` менял на `int` аналогично:
[image: long long]

[image: int]

А теперь и момент переполнения на примере:
[image: Дерево]

На скриншоте я красным обвёл две цифры и операцию умножить и действительно, если умножить число `-817925191` на `9`, то получится `-7*10^9`, что и переполняет `int`, содержащий `2*10^9!`.
По просьбе прикрепляю код и с `long long` и с `int`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
string prov;
bool IsCifra(char a)
{
    if (a != '*' && a != '+' && a != '-' && a != '/')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
long long calculator(long long f, char a, long long s)
{
    if (a == '*')
    {
        return f * s;
    }
    if (a == '+')
    {
        return f + s;
    }
    if (a == '-')
    {
        return f - s;
    }
    if (s == 0)
    {
        prov = "NO";
        return 0;
    }
    return f / s;
}
class Tree
{
public:
    struct TreeElement
    {
        int child1_pos, child2_pos;
        char val;
    };
private:


    long long deep_calculate(const int& pos);
    int deep_add(const int& pos, const string& s);
public:
    size_t tree_size_;
    TreeElement* tree_ptr_;
    Tree(const size_t& element_count, const string& s);
    ~Tree()
    {
        delete[] tree_ptr_;
    }
    long long calculate();
};
Tree::Tree(const size_t& element_count, const string& s)
{
    this->tree_ptr_ = new TreeElement[element_count];
    this->tree_size_ = element_count;
    tree_ptr_[0].val = s[0];
    tree_ptr_[s.size() - 1].child1_pos = -1;
    tree_ptr_[s.size() - 1].child2_pos = -1;
    deep_add(0, s);
}
long long Tree::calculate()
{
    return deep_calculate(0);
}
long long Tree::deep_calculate(const int& pos)
{
    if (prov == "NO")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (IsCifra(tree_ptr_[pos].val))
    {
        return tree_ptr_[pos].val - '0';
    }
    long long first = deep_calculate(tree_ptr_[pos].child1_pos), second = deep_calculate(tree_ptr_[pos].child2_pos);
    long long zn = calculator(first, tree_ptr_[pos].val, second);
    return zn;
}
int Tree::deep_add(const int& pos, const string& s)
{
    TreeElement* arr = tree_ptr_;
    // считаем, что первый ребёнок всегда на +1 ячейку от родителя
    arr[pos].child1_pos = pos + 1;
    arr[pos + 1].val = s[pos + 1];
    if (IsCifra(arr[arr[pos].child1_pos].val))
    {
        //первый ребёнок - цифра, тогда второй ребёнок идёт сразу после первого в строке
        arr[pos + 1].child1_pos = -1;
        arr[pos + 1].child2_pos = -1;

        arr[pos].child2_pos = pos + 2;
        arr[pos + 2].val = s[pos + 2];
        //закинули данные
    }
    else
    {
        //первый ребёнок не цифра и надо понять, где лежит второй ребёнок
        //запускаем для первого ребёнка 
        int child2pos;
        child2pos = deep_add(pos + 1, s);
        //заполняем
        arr[pos].child2_pos = child2pos + 1;
        arr[child2pos + 1].val = s[child2pos + 1];
        //готово
    }
    if (IsCifra(arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].val))
    {
        //если вторая - цифра
        arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].child1_pos = -1;
        arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].child2_pos = -1;
        return arr[pos].child2_pos;
    }
    else
    {
        return deep_add(arr[pos].child2_pos, s);
    }
}


int main()
{
    ifstream datain;
    datain.open("input.txt");
    string s;
    datain >> s;
    ofstream dataout;
    dataout.open("output.txt");
    if (s.size() == 1)
    {
        dataout << s[0] - '0';
        return 0;
    }
    Tree tree(s.size(), s);
    long long ans = tree.calculate();
    if (prov == "NO")
    {
        dataout << prov;
    }
    else
    {
        dataout << ans;
    }
}
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
string prov;
bool IsCifra(char a)
{
    if (a != '*' && a != '+' && a != '-' && a != '/')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int calculator(int f, char a, int s)
{
    if (a == '*')
    {
        return f * s;
    }
    if (a == '+')
    {
        return f + s;
    }
    if (a == '-')
    {
        return f - s;
    }
    if (s == 0)
    {
        prov = "NO";
        return 0;
    }
    return f / s;
}
class Tree
{
public:
    struct TreeElement
    {
        int child1_pos, child2_pos;
        char val;
    };
private:


    int deep_calculate(const int& pos);
    int deep_add(const int& pos, const string& s);
public:
    size_t tree_size_;
    TreeElement* tree_ptr_;
    Tree(const size_t& element_count, const string& s);
    ~Tree()
    {
        delete[] tree_ptr_;
    }
    int calculate();
};
Tree::Tree(const size_t& element_count, const string& s)
{
    this->tree_ptr_ = new TreeElement[element_count];
    this->tree_size_ = element_count;
    tree_ptr_[0].val = s[0];
    tree_ptr_[s.size() - 1].child1_pos = -1;
    tree_ptr_[s.size() - 1].child2_pos = -1;
    deep_add(0, s);
}
int Tree::calculate()
{
    return deep_calculate(0);
}
int Tree::deep_calculate(const int& pos)
{
    if (prov == "NO")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (IsCifra(tree_ptr_[pos].val))
    {
        return tree_ptr_[pos].val - '0';
    }
    int first = deep_calculate(tree_ptr_[pos].child1_pos), second = deep_calculate(tree_ptr_[pos].child2_pos);
    int zn = calculator(first, tree_ptr_[pos].val, second);
    return zn;
}
int Tree::deep_add(const int& pos, const string& s)
{
    TreeElement* arr = tree_ptr_;
    // считаем, что первый ребёнок всегда на +1 ячейку от родителя
    arr[pos].child1_pos = pos + 1;
    arr[pos + 1].val = s[pos + 1];
    if (IsCifra(arr[arr[pos].child1_pos].val))
    {
        //первый ребёнок - цифра, тогда второй ребёнок идёт сразу после первого в строке
        arr[pos + 1].child1_pos = -1;
        arr[pos + 1].child2_pos = -1;

        arr[pos].child2_pos = pos + 2;
        arr[pos + 2].val = s[pos + 2];
        //закинули данные
    }
    else
    {
        //первый ребёнок не цифра и надо понять, где лежит второй ребёнок
        //запускаем для первого ребёнка 
        int child2pos;
        child2pos = deep_add(pos + 1, s);
        //заполняем
        arr[pos].child2_pos = child2pos + 1;
        arr[child2pos + 1].val = s[child2pos + 1];
        //готово
    }
    if (IsCifra(arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].val))
    {
        //если вторая - цифра
        arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].child1_pos = -1;
        arr[arr[pos].child2_pos].child2_pos = -1;
        return arr[pos].child2_pos;
    }
    else
    {
        return deep_add(arr[pos].child2_pos, s);
    }
}


int main()
{
    ifstream datain;
    datain.open("input.txt");
    string s;
    datain >> s;
    ofstream dataout;
    dataout.open("output.txt");
    if (s.size() == 1)
    {
        dataout << s[0] - '0';
        return 0;
    }
    Tree tree(s.size(), s);
    int ans = tree.calculate();
    if (prov == "NO")
    {
        dataout << prov;
    }
    else
    {
        dataout << ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: И первый и второй вариант?

Comment: Сделал, как и просили!

Comment: Спасибо. Плюсик от меня.

Answer (score 4):

Вот простенький код, который считает результат

```
#include <iostream>

int parse(const std::string& s, int& pos) {
  if (pos >= s.length()) throw "end of string!";
  char c = s[pos];
  pos++;
  if (isdigit(c)) return (c - '0');
  int a1 = parse(s, pos);
  int a2 = parse(s, pos);
  switch (c) {
    case '+': return a1+a2;
    case '-': return a1-a2;
    case '*': return a1*a2;
    case '/': return a1/a2;
  }
  throw "unxpected";
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  std::string s = "-+/*+36+--+*2--+/+8*9*+*+3*/6519-**+**4-+/-/3+1*-*287-97+*+*++*22**3+*33451778921491874825497385431";
  int pos = 0;
  int r = parse(s, pos);
  std::cout << "answer is " << r << "\n";
}
```

да, в нем нет многих проверок и он рассчитывает, что исходная строка корректная, но в таких задачах это допустимо.

Если посмотреть на код, то понятно, что если текущий символ цифра, значит нашли  "листок", если же там символ операции, то нужно прочитать двух "детей", что можно сделать рекурсивно. Когда этот код разберете, вот другой, более близкий к заданию.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct Node
{
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
    char value = ' ';
    int calc = 0;
    Node() : left{nullptr}, right{nullptr}, value{' '} {}
    Node(char c) : left{nullptr}, right{nullptr}, value{c} { assert(isdigit(c)); calc = c - '0';}
    Node(Node* l, Node* r, char c) : left{l}, right{r}, value{c} {
      switch(c) {
        case '+': calc = l->calc + r->calc; break;
        case '-': calc = l->calc - r->calc; break;
        case '*': calc = l->calc * r->calc; break;
        case '/': calc = l->calc / r->calc; break;
      }
    }

    ~Node() {
      delete left;
      delete right;
    }
};

Node* parse(const std::string& s, int& pos) {
  if (pos >= s.length()) throw "end of string!";
  char c = s[pos];
  pos++;
  if (isdigit(c)) {return new Node(c);};
  Node* left = parse(s, pos);
  Node* right = parse(s, pos);
  switch (c) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
      return new Node{left, right, c};
  }
  throw "unxpected";
  return nullptr;
}

void print(Node* n, int level) {
  if (n == nullptr) return;
  std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << n->value << " = " << n->calc << "\n";
  print(n->left, level+1);
  print(n->right, level+1);
}

int main()
{
  std::string s = "-+/*+36+--+*2--+/+8*9*+*+3*/6519-**+**4-+/-/3+1*-*287-97+*+*++*22**3+*33451778921491874825497385431";
  int pos = 0;
  Node* r = parse(s, pos);
  print(r, 0);
  delete r;
}
```

Здесь чуточку больше кода и проверок. А также оно печатает дерево, добавляя к "нодам с операциями" текущий результат, Вы сможете сравнить с своим деревом и поискать ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если вы поменяете тип с `int` на `long long` переполнение исчезнет.

Comment: Да, всё верно, довольно интересная находка получилась!

Comment: осталось только определится - нужно тест пройти или завалить тестовую систему

Comment: А на самом деле и то, и то)